# Is it possible to found most of the errors in programs written in Haskell by adding a new feature, something I call it "subtype system", to Haskell?

Tags: exception, haskell, types, subclass

I have learned Haskell for about one year, and came up with a question that could the talented compiler writers add a new feature called "subset" by me to enhance the Haskell's type system to catch many errors including IOExceptions in compiling stage. I'm novice of Theory of types, and forgive my wishful thinking.

My initial purpose is not how to solve the problem but to know whether there exists a related solution but because of some reasons the solution is not introduced to Haskell.

Haskell is nearly perfect in my mind except for some little things, and I will express my wish to Haskell of the future in the following lines.

The following is the major one:

If we can define a type, which is just a "subset" of `Int` assuming Haskell allows us to do that, like bellow:

```
data IntNotZero = Int {except `0`} -- certainly it is not legal in Haskell, but I just assume that Haskell allows us to define a type as a "subset" of an already existing type. I'm novice of Theory of types, and forgive me.
```

And If a function needs a parameter of `Int`, a variable of `IntNotZero`, which is just a "subset" of `Int`, can also be a parameter of the function. But, If a function needs a `IntNotZero`, then a `Int` is illegal.

For example:

```
div' :: Int -> IntNotZero -> Int
div' = div

aFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int --If we casually write it, then the compiler will complain for type conflict.
aFunction = div'

aFunction2 :: Int -> Int -> Int --we have to distinguish between `Int` and `IntNotZero`.
aFunction2 m n = type n of --An assumed grammar like `case ... of` to separate "subset" from its complement. `case ...of` only works on different patterns.
                   IntNotZero -> m `div` n
                   otherwise  -> m + n
```

For a more useful example:

```
data HandleNotClosed = Handle {not closed} --this type infers a Handle not closed

hGetContents' :: HandleNotClosed -> IO String --this function needs a HandleNotClosed and a Handle will make a type conflict.
hGetContents' = hGetContents

wrongMain = do
         ...
         h <- openFile "~/xxx/aa" ReadMode
         ... -- we do many tasks with h and we may casually closed h
         contents <- hGetContents' h --this will raise a type conflict, because h has type of Handle not HandleNotClosed.
         ...

rightMain = do
         ...
         h <- openFile "~/xxx/aa" ReadMode
         ... -- we do many tasks with h and we may casually closed h
         type h of -- the new grammar.
              HandleNotClosed -> do
                                   contents <- hGetContents' h
                                   ...
              otherwise       -> ...
```

If we combine ordinary IO with Exception to a new "supset", then we may get free of IOErrors.

Comment: You want dependent types.  A problem with those is that you will have to have proofs in your code (like proving a value isn't 0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want sounds similar to "refinement types" à la [Liquid Haskell](http://goto.ucsd.edu/~rjhala/liquid/haskell/blog/blog/2013/01/01/refinement-types-101.lhs/). This is an external tool that allows you to "refine" your Haskell types by specifying additional predicates that hold over your types. To check that these hold, you use an [SMT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_Modulo_Theories) to verify all the constraints have been satisfied.

The following code snippets are taken from their introductory blog post.

For example, you could write the type that `zero` is `0`:

```
{-@ zero :: { v : Int | v = 0 } @-}
zero :: Int
zero = 0
```

You'll notice that the syntax for types looks just like set notation for math--you're defining a new type as a subset of the old on. In this case, you're defining the type of `Int`s that are equal to 0.

You can use this system to write a safe divide function:

```
{-@ divide :: Int -> { v : Int | v != 0 } -> Int @-}
divide :: Int -> Int -> Int
divide n 0 = error "Cannot divide by 0."
divide n d = n `div` d
```

When you actually try to compile this program, Liquid Haskell will see that having 0 as the denominator violates the predicate and so the call to `error` cannot happen. Moreover, when you try to use `divide`, it will check that the argument you pass in cannot be 0.

Of course, to make this useful, you have to be able to add information about the postconditions of your functions, not just the preconditions. You can just do this by refining the result type of the function; for example, you can imagine the following type for `abs`:

```
{-@ abs :: Int -> { v : Int | 0 <= v } @-}
```

Now the type system knows that the result of calling `abs` will never be negative, and it can take advantage of this fact when it needs to verify your program.

Like other people mentioned, using this sort of type system means you will have to have proofs in your code. The advantage of Liquid Haskell is that it uses an SMT solver to generate the proof for you automatically--you just have to write the assertions.

Liquid Haskell is still a research project, and it's limited by what can reasonably be done with an SMT solver. I haven't used it myself, but it looks really awesome and seems to be exactly what you want. One thing I'm not sure about is how it interacts with custom types and `IO`--something you might want to look into yourself.

Comment: Many thanks to you, your answer is just what I'm looking forward to.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the compiler can't determine if something is of type `IntNotZero`. For example:

```
f :: Int -> IntNotZero
f x = someExtremlyComplexComputation
```

the compiler would have to prove that `someExtremlyComplexComputation` doesn't produce a zero result, which is in general impossible.

One way how to approach this is in plain Haskell to create a module that hides the representation of `IntNotZero` and publishes only a [smart constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors) such as

```
module MyMod (IntNotZero(), intNotZero) where

newtype IntNotZero = IntNotZero Int

intNotZero :: Int -> IntNotZero
intNotZero 0 = error "Zero argument"
intNotZero x = IntNotZero x

-- etc
```

The obvious drawback is that the constraint is checked only at runtime.

---

There are more complex systems than Haskell that use [Dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). These are types that depend on values, and they allow you to express just what you want. Unfortunately these systems are rather complex and not much widespread. If you're interested in the subject, I suggest you to read [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) by Adam Chlipala.

Comment: Thanks, my initial purpose is not to solve a problem but to know whether there exists a related solution but because of some reasons the solution is not introduced to Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

We have types and we have values. A Type is a set of (infinite) values. `String` is a type and all the possible string values are part of the `String` set. Now, the most important distinction about types and values is this - Types are about compile time and Values are available at runtime.

If we look at you first example which talks about a new **type** which is subtype (or subset) of Int type such that "the **value** of the Int can't be zero", which means you want to define a type which put some restrictions on a value BUT types are compile time and values are runtime things - a compile time thing can't restrict a runtime thing because the runtime thing is not there yet for compile time thing to consume.

Similarly the handle value is a runtime thing and only at runtime you can know if it is closed or not and for that you have functions to check whether the handle is closed or not.
IO is all about runtime and you can't use a type system to get free of IOErrors.

For modeling runtime failures you can use data types like `Maybe` or `Either` to indicate that the function may not be able to do what is was supposed to do and as these data types implements functors, moands and other computations patterns you can easily compose them.

A type system is more of a structuring/design tool which make things more explicit and clear and makes you think more about your design but it can't do what **functions** are supposed to do.

The film is : Typed Lambda calculus. Lambda in lead role, Typed in supporting role :)

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but I mean we have to do "sub set checking"  by hand because the function needs the very "sub set" which satisfying some restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @augustss's comment, it's quite possible using dependently typed languages. Haskell is not exactly dependently typed, but it's close enough that dependent types can be ["faked"](http://www.jonmsterling.com/posts/2012-11-10-faking-it-with-style.html).

People don't today commonly use dependent types for several reasons

1. they're still very much research topics
2. they complicate and weaken type inference
3. they're somewhat more difficult to use in some circumstances
4. they can cause type-checking to take much longer or even fail to terminate, and
5. it's just more difficult to create production dependently-typed compilers.

That said, proponents of dependent typing find the error reduction you're looking for quite tenable. They also anticipate better safety and faster compiled binaries. Finally, dependently typed systems can be used as "proof systems" for mathematics. For a very current example consider the ["Homotopy Type Theory" Agda code](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT-Agda) which formally proves many of the assertions of a new field of dependent typing math.

For a taste of dependent typing you can read/explore either Pierce's [*Software Foundations*](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/) or Chlipala's [*Certified Programming with Dependent Types*](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/).

With dependent types you might introduce a type like this

```
div :: Int -> (x :: Int) -> (Inequal x 0) -> Int
```

where the second argument introduces a *dependency* of the type on the actual *value* of the argument and the third argument demands a *proof* of the *proposition* that `x /= 0`. With such a proof in hand (so long as nobody cheats and uses `undefined` as that proof) it's possible to feel confident dividing by the second argument could never be undefined.

The challenge comes from creating (automatically or manually) a value to pass in as the third argument. For such a simple example it may not be too difficult, but it becomes possible to encode demands for proofs that are very difficult to generate, or even impossible.

As an example of another advantage, consider

```
fold1 :: (f :: a -> a -> a) -> Associative f -> [a] -> a
```

which, ignoring the second argument, is just a regular fold. The second argument could be a proof that `f` associates and thus allows us to use a tree-like merging algorithm with log complexity instead of linear. But, in order to "prove" `Associative` we need to embed a theory of application and association into our types and have the competency to create proofs within it.

Simpler invariants exist such as the all-prevalent `Vec` type of "fixed-length vectors". These are lists where the length of the list (a *value*) is included in the type allowing us to have nice things like

```
(++) :: Vec n a -> Vec m a -> Vec (n + m) a
```

which, if we have some good theories of addition (or, more generally, magmas, monoids, and groups) in our type system then it isn't too difficult to create our result type which holds information about the way lengths of `Vec`s interact under concatenation.

Comment: Although I cannot understand your answer well, your answer is really helpful to many other questions in my mind. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Dependent types are quite weird when you first look at them. I really suggest *Software Foundations* or *Certified Programming* if you're interested in learning more. They both use Coq which is modeled off of OCaml, but if you can survive on the sparse documentation then Agda is a Haskell-like implementation of these techniques.